# how to combine multiple rows to one row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe with multiple rows of same name but with different attributes, I want to combine the rows to form a single row for data analysis

Existing data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name' : ['ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE'], 
     'A': ['A1','','','',''],
     'B': ['','B1','','',''],
     'C': ['','','','',''],
     'D': ['','','','D1',''],
     'E': ['','','','','E1'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

o= {'name' : ['ZEE'], 'A': ['A1'],'B': ['B1'],'C': [''],'D': ['D1'],'E': ['E1']}
o = pd.DataFrame(data=o)
o
```

Input :

| NAME | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zee | A1 |  |  |  |  |
| Zee |  | B1 |  |  |  |
| Zee |  |  |  |  |  |
| Zee |  |  |  | D1 |  |
| Zee |  |  |  |  | E1 |

Output:

| NAME | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zee | A1 | B1 |  | D1 | E1 |

Comment: `df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False).apply(lambda : x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates('NAME')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple case of `groupby()`.  Conversion of empty strings to NaN is important

```
d = {'name' : ['ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE'], 
     'A': ['A1','','','',''],
     'B': ['','B1','','',''],
     'C': ['','','','',''],
     'D': ['','','','D1',''],
     'E': ['','','','','E1'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.replace({"":np.nan}).groupby("name").first().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure this will fit your purposes in any use case but `df.groupby("name").sum()` should provide exactly the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're sure there will never be more than one value in each column, then you can use the "max" aggregator of Panda's groupby method. If these are strings, this will return the string with the most characters. In your case this is fine, since `len('A1') > len('')`. If you were using integers, it would return the highest value. Since you have strings, and there is only one non-empty entry per column, this should be fine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame{
    'name' : ['ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE', 'ZEE'],
    'A': ['A1','','','',''],
    'B': ['','B1','','',''],
    'C': ['','','','',''],
    'D': ['','','','D1',''],
    'E': ['','','','','E1'],
}

df.groupby('name').max()
```

Results in

```
       A   B C   D   E
name                  
ZEE   A1  B1    D1  E1
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can replace the '' with np.nan, and use backfill NA, then the first row is the target.

```
df.replace('', np.nan).fillna(method='bfill').iloc[[0]]
```